# Why my pen tool paths not divided?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create low-poly image by create triangles with pen tool.

1. I made a closed path square and after that closed i pressed return.
2. I hovered my mouse to top left corner and drew a line to close to the middle of the square (pointy side of triangle) while pressing shift.
3. Then i pressed the bottom left corner of the square while pressing shift.
4. pressed return.
5. Pathfinder -> Divide.

Then i went to Eyedropper tool and tried to fill. There is the problem, it fills BOTH the triangle AND square (only square selected). I need to fill the triangle only!

[image]

Soo... the triangle only has two lines, i hoped it would use the line of the left side of the square to close to triangle but it didn't?

How do you close paths for low-poly triangles?

Comment: You don't need to use pathfinder to color triangles even if they're not closed...

Comment: so if one of the answers solves your problem or you figured out a different solution, please either accept one of the answers or add your own and accept it. If you want to know more about the site, please check the [help]

Answer (score 1):

You could try joining the open points: Select the two points on the left side of the triangle using the Direct Selection Tool (White arrow) and press CTRL+J.

That should close the path and make the third side of the triangle. At that point you could change the fill of the triangle, or select both the square and triangle together before retrying your Pathfinder operation.

*Edit: In case you're new to Illustrator, selecting more than one point (or object) can be done by clicking on the first item and then holding Shift while clicking on the next one.*

Answer (score 1):

Your path was not filled as you expected so either:

1. your newly drawn triangle wasn't actually touching the square, easily verifiable if you zoom in close enough. Just use the smart guides (View > Smart Guides) when creating a new shape to ensure the new vertices touch the existing shape.
2. you could've just filled the triangle as it was; just select it by clicking on the stroke (not inside the triangle, if it doesn't have a fill you'll be selecting the square behind it) and add the fill color.

Answer (score 1):

Select the triangle with the **Selection Tool** (black arrow)

Choose `Object > Path > Join` (Command/Ctrl + j)

Fill as desired

There's no need for Pathfinder.